# What is so special about categories that lead people to use them to "formalize math"?

Tags: category-theory, formal-languages

There are countless interesting structures - lists, trees, maps, graphs. Yet, categories - which, if I understand, is just a graph with some constraints on its shape - are apparently special somehow, in that people propose using it to "formalize all of math".

What is so different about this specific data structure that makes it so special?

Comment: I would say that what makes category theory worth studying is not that it "is apparently special somehow," but rather it captures things that are similar about various fields of study.  Capturing the repeated similarities gives one a nice perspective on how other topics are (in various ways) special, without necessarily making category theory really special.

Comment: Maths is about finding patterns and abstracting them into something expressible.  Category theory is useful because at its foundations its a very simple structure that is good at expressing abstractions.

Comment: Quite true all that you say from a higher perspective, and I am in fact a big fan of it. But, what does it help in proving anything that was not known already about any specific field of study?

Comment: A category is *not* just a graph with some constraints on its shape! The composition of morphisms is extra structure, not an extra property, and it's by far the most interesting data in a category.

Answer (score 3):

Category theory allows us to prove theorems that apply to many different mathematical theories. For example, the categorical theorem that says that left adjoint functors commute with colimits can be applied to prove that the tensor product is right exact and to prove that the suspension functor commutes with wedge products. Those results can be (easily) proved without category theory, but the spirit of modern math is to work with maximal generality in order to simplify the theories.

Moreover, it is fundamental for comparisons of different theories. For example, it is well-known that a module over a group algebra is the same as a representation of this group, or that the homotopy theory of simplicial sets is the same as the homotopy theory of spaces, but these statements make the more sense when expressed in terms of category theory.

Finally, many modern theories wouldn't exist without category theory. For example, modern homotopy theory revolves around the notions of model, higher or enriched categories. Without category theory, these notions would be very difficult to define/use.

And there are a lot of other things that I didn't mention that show that category theory is, at the moment, the right framework to do "general mathematics".

Comment: So, basically, this particular structure somehow has such a quality that, if you prove things about it, you also prove things about numbers, topologies, graphs, and whatever more you can think of, "for free"? Or, in other words, if you look it carefully enough, everything is a category?

Comment: I wouldn't say that "everything is a category", we don't know what math will look like in a 100 years, maybe a more fundamental notion will appear. But at the moment, category theory has the practical advantage of being applied to many mathematical theories and as you say give results "for free". And as I mentionned, lots of modern theories like homotopy theory, algebraic geometry, quantum algebra etc, are really built on category theory and don't just use it as a tool.

Comment: I think this answer helped a lot. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It isn't merely the data structure that makes categories "special" but the operations that can be performed on them.  Functors, in particular, relate corresponding elements in different categories and can show how apparently different mathematical structures are—generally at a very abstract level—in fact the same.